# Plotting points according to a regression fitted in stat_smooth()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a plot using ggplot2 package that contain four different regressions which were fitted on stat_smooth(), as follows:

```
ggplot(NULL, aes(x = time, y = shoot)) + 
stat_smooth(data = data.0.cr, method = "lm", formula = y ~ I(x), se = FALSE, linetype = "F1", color = "black") + 
stat_smooth(data = data.0.pr, method = "lm", formula = y ~ I(x^2) + I(x^3), se = FALSE, linetype = "solid", color = "black") + 
stat_smooth(data = data.35.cr, method = "lm", formula = y ~ I(x), se = FALSE, linetype = "dotted", color = "black") + 
stat_smooth(data = data.35.pr, method = "lm", formula = y ~ I(x) + I(x^2) + I(x^3), se = FALSE, linetype = "12345678", color = "black")
```

One of my data.frame looks like this (I specified one data for each stat_smooth()):

```
dose time genotype block  shoot
0     0   cr       1      120.3168
0     0   cr       2      123.0590
0     0   cr       3      108.0160
0     1   cr       1      103.3750
0     1   cr       2      146.7620
0     1   cr       3      92.5630
0     4   cr       1      83.2540
0     4   cr       2      131.2680
0     4   cr       3      122.0290
0     7   cr       1      136.7460
0     7   cr       2      136.5300
0     7   cr       3      115.0080
```

As each factor needed to be fitted in a different way, I wrote four stat_smooth() and to distinguish each one I used four different linetypes.

What I would like to include is points along each regression ploted. In other words, I would like to define the line like:

Reg1: solid line and triangles
Reg2: dashed line and triangles
Reg3: solid line and circles
Reg4: dashed line and circles.

Is it possible to do that instead of define different kinds of linetypes? (using some geom_point() or similar)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where is your dataset?

Comment: Hi @ycw, I edited my post to include an example of one of my dataset